# Iterating over string in Swift to fetch mobile number

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to fetch mobile numbers from a long list of string which contains mobile number written in it separated by comma.

E.g:

```
8809394847, 9988338847, 9933883384, 8833938373
```

In my code, I have a function which accepts mobile number to do a particular job. My entire string is stored in a variable called inputData.

I tried using this code:

```
let mob = inputData.index(of: " ") ?? inputData.endIndex
    let mobile = inputData[..<mob]
    MyJob(phone: mobile). //Function that accepts mobile number
```

But it makes no sense.

My original code :

```
@IBAction func clickButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    inputData = textView.text!

    MyJob(phone: mobile).  //Calling function

}
```

I need to run some kind of loop inside the clickButton function to fetch the mobile numbers and send it to the MyJob function one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `String.components(separatedBy:)` to split your String into separate phone numbers.

```
@IBAction func clickButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let numbersString = textView.text!
    let numbers = numbersString.components(separatedBy: ", ")
    for number in numbers {
        MyJob(phone: number)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You better try components separation string function

```
@IBAction func clickButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

  inputData = textView.text!

  var mobileNumbers = inputData.components(separatedBy: ",")

  for mobile in mobileNumbers {
     MyJob(phone: mobile) //Calling function
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `components(separatedBy` with parameter `", "` to make an array then use a loop for example

```
let string = "8809394847, 9988338847, 9933883384, 8833938373"
let phoneNumbers = string.components(separatedBy: ", ")
for phoneNumber in phoneNumbers {
    MyJob(phone: phoneNumber)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function to get array of substrings as [subStrings] like

```
let str = "8809394847,9988338847,9933883384, 8833938373"
let arrayOfNumbers = str.split(separator: ",")
print(arrayOfNumbers)
```

output:
    ["8809394847", "9988338847", "9933883384", "8833938373"]

iterate this array and send it to the MyJob function one by one.

Hope this helps.